# Django не происходит перенаправления при регистрации

Tags: python, django

пишу сайт, сделала модель User, форму регистрации и view для регистрации.
модель User:

```
class User(models.Model):
    """Класс, описывающий пользователя"""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Имя пользователя")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Фамилия пользователя")
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=254, verbose_name="Электронная почта пользователя"
    )

    # favourites = add to favourites

    def validate_length(
            value, length=11
    ):  # Display a message when creating a classified
        if len(str(value)) != length:
            raise ValidationError("%s is not the correct length" % value)

    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        validators=[validate_length],
        verbose_name="Номер телефона",
        default=None,
    )  # Display contact phone number

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Пользователь"
        verbose_name_plural = "Пользователи"
```

Форма для регистрации:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Имя'}),
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Фамилия'}),
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
    )
    phone_number = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Номер телефона'}),
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Пароль'}),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Подтверждение пароля'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'password1', 'password2'
        ]
```

класс представления для регистрации:

```
class RegistrationUserView(FormView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = 'login'
    template_name = 'apartment_app/registration.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(RegistrationUserView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(RegistrationUserView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("<int:advertisement_id>/", advertisement, name="advertisement"),
    path("new/<int:advertisement_id>", make_advertisement_id, name="new_advertisement"),
    path('registration/', RegistrationUserView.as_view(), name='registration'),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

при попытке регистрации не всплывает никаких ошибок, однако после нажатия кнопки "зарегистрироваться" перенаправления на login не происходит, форма просто очищается и все. в чем же проблема? как реализовать перенаправление?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: А где-то редирект используете? Есть метод https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect . А так, это заставит сервер вернуть клиенту ответ html с кодом из 3xx и в заголовке ответа будет ссылка на которую нужно сделать переход

Comment: использую success_url, но также пробовала redirect, reverse_lazy. ничего не менялось. подозреваю что он не пропускает форму почему-то, и проблема в этом, а не в самом перенаправлении